# R reduce code format

Tags: r

I'll try to explain what i need help with.

Example: i want to add a design parameter on my dataframe `"transactionTableMergeCost"`
this is my attempt to do so:

```
transactionTableMergeCost$roi<-(transactionTableMergeCost$revenue-transactionTableMergeCost$spend)/transactionTableMergeCost$spend
```

Can this code be shorter(something like this?)

```
transactionTableMergeCost->
@this$roi<-(@this$revenue - @this$spend) / @this$spend
```

Or is the first way the shortest one possible?

Comment: Try `?with` or `?transform` - e.g. `transactionTableMergeCost <- transform(transactionTableMergeCost, roi = (revenue - spend) / spend)`. Or try the `data.table` package which when installed and operating on a `data.table` object lets you do things like `transactionTableMergeCost[, roi := (revenue - spend) / spend)]`

Comment: Or make the name of your data shorter.  `transactionTableMergeCost` is way long.  Maybe `tTMC`

Answer (score 0):

`with()` is the simplest way to go IMO... And using shorter names wouldn't hurt!

```
tbl <- data.frame(revenue=rnorm(n = 10, mean = 10000, sd = 1000),
                  spend=rnorm(n = 10, mean = 9000, sd = 1000))
tbl$roi <- with(data = tbl, expr = (revenue-spend)/spend)
tbl
     revenue     spend         roi
1  10900.029  8286.808  0.31534715
2   8998.217 11095.703 -0.18903590
3  10204.678  9394.989  0.08618313
4  10218.754  9365.915  0.09105775
5   9147.773  8023.789  0.14008150
6   9573.119  8538.044  0.12123093
7   8991.229 10439.290 -0.13871259
8  11588.986  9844.280  0.17723050
9   9535.081  9055.307  0.05298270
10 10280.902  8352.768  0.23083772
```